# Can I use boostrap datepaginator only for Year

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to use bootstrap [datepaginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator) as only Year selection. I don't know if  it is even possible. If it's anyway possible please show me a way. I need it badly.

Comment: Put the date picker into the year selection state and do not allow them to change it

Comment: Mr. @johnny5, would you please be little more specific ?

Comment: Oops thought that was the date Picker